# Can you have a shliach do something you have sworn not to do?

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, shlichus-agency

If you swear not to do something can you send someone to do it for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sefer Tiferes LiMoshe (יור''ד סימן שי''ז) says you may not as normally You might say אין שליח לדבר עבירה (there is no sin through messenger) this situation is different because that is when you both have the Sin. Here only the sender has the sin so we sayשלוחו כמותו the messenger is like the person himself and he can not send someone else to do it.

Comment: It's not so simple, see the end of SA OC Siman 263 about someone who was Mekabel Shabbos and asks someone else to do a Melacha for him (there's a long Kuntres Acharon in SA Horav there dealing with the Shitos). Also in Siman 527:20 if one is fasting on Yom Tov (and he made an Eiruv Tavshilin) the Ramah says he can't cook, but the Achronim are Mefakfeik in it. See Mishna Berurah #65.